# Compiler does not allow to use exit() function in C

Tags: c

I am doing an online course in programming, And I've got assignment to complete, So my problem is I'm not able to use `exit(0)`; in this online compiler, I dont know which compiler is this, however the course is powered by Google.

Whatsoever, the error i get is :

```
Program:18:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'exit' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
Program:18:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit' [enabled by default]
```

So I'm helpless, It works fine in other compilers , ie DEV c++ and turbo c++ , So can anyone help me please!

Comment: Program should compile. Include `stdlib.h` to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `stdlib.h` for `exit`.

Comment: @Roma: if the answer worked for you consider marking it as accepted "the tick sign under the votes arrows".